# Error executing SQLite command: 'too many SQL variables' Azure PullAsync limitation in xamarin form android

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, xamarin-android-player

This looks like limitation from Microsoft azure mobile client for offline sync service for android. 
In my xamarin form application i have 40 azure tables to sync with remote. Whenever the particular request(_abcTable.PullAsync) has the more number record like 5K, PullAsync returns the exception saying that : **Error executing SQLite command: 'too many SQL variables'**. 
That pull async URL goes like this :  **https://abc-xyz.hds.host.com/AppHostMobile/tables/XXXXXXResponse?$filter=(updatedAt ge datetimeoffset'2017-06-20T13:26:17.8200000%2B00:00')&$orderby=updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=5000&ProjectId=2&__includeDeleted=true**.

But in postman i can see the same Url returning the 5K records and Works fine in iPhone device as well but failing only in android.
From the above PullAsync request if i change the "top" parameter value from 5000 to 500 it works fine in android but takes more time. Do i have any other alternatives without limiting the performance. 

Package version:
 Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client  version="3.1.0"
 Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore" version=“3.1.0”  
 Microsoft.Bcl version="1.1.10"  
 Microsoft.Bcl.Build version="1.0.21"  
 SQLite.Net.Core-PCL version="3.1.1"  
 SQLite.Net-PCL version="3.1.1"   
 SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green version="1.1.2"  
 SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.2"  
 SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.2"  
 SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.2"
 Please let me know if i need to provide more information. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way around this issue?

Comment: @abrull No luck

Answer (score 0):

> Error executing SQLite command: 'too many SQL variables

Per my understanding, your sqlite may touch the [Maximum Number Of Host Parameters In A Single SQL Statement](https://sqlite.org/limits.html) mentions as follows:

> A host parameter is a place-holder in an SQL statement that is filled in using one of the sqlite3_bind_XXXX() interfaces. Many SQL programmers are familiar with using a question mark ("?") as a host parameter. SQLite also supports named host parameters prefaced by ":", "$", or "@" and numbered host parameters of the form "?123".
>
> Each host parameter in an SQLite statement is assigned a number. The numbers normally begin with 1 and increase by one with each new parameter. However, when the "?123" form is used, the host parameter number is the number that follows the question mark.
>
> SQLite allocates space to hold all host parameters between 1 and the largest host parameter number used. Hence, an SQL statement that contains a host parameter like ?1000000000 would require gigabytes of storage. This could easily overwhelm the resources of the host machine. To prevent excessive memory allocations, **the maximum value of a host parameter number is SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER, which defaults to 999**.
>
> The maximum host parameter number can be lowered at run-time using the sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER,size) interface.

I refered [Debugging the Offline Cache](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#debugging-the-offline-cache) and init my `MobileServiceSQLiteStore` as follows:

```
var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStoreWithLogging("localstore.db");
```

I logged all the SQL commands that are executed against the SQLite store when invoking `pullasync`. I found that after successfully retrieve response from mobile backend via the following request:

`https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?$filter=((UserId%20eq%20null)%20and%20(updatedAt%20ge%20datetimeoffset'1970-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.0000000%2B00%3A00'))&$orderby=updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true`

`Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore.dll` would execute the following sql statement for updating the related local table:

> BEGIN TRANSACTION
>
> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO [TodoItem] ([id]) VALUES (@p0),(@p1),(@p2),(@p3),(@p4),(@p5),(@p6),(@p7),(@p8),(@p9),(@p10),(@p11),(@p12),(@p13),(@p14),(@p15),(@p16),(@p17),(@p18),(@p19),(@p20),(@p21),(@p22),(@p23),(@p24),(@p25),(@p26),(@p27),(@p28),(@p29),(@p30),(@p31),(@p32),(@p33),(@p34),(@p35),(@p36),(@p37),(@p38),(@p39),(@p40),(@p41),(@p42),(@p43),(@p44),(@p45),(@p46),(@p47),(@p48),(@p49)
>
> UPDATE [TodoItem] SET [Text] = @p0,[UserId] = @p1 WHERE [id] = @p2
>
> UPDATE [TodoItem] SET [Text] = @p0,[UserId] = @p1 WHERE [id] = @p2
>
> .
>
> .
>
> COMMIT TRANSACTION

Per my understanding, you could try to set `MaxPageSize` up to 999. Also, this limitation is from sqlite and the update processing is automatically handled by `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore`. For now, I haven't find any approach to override the processing from `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore`.